# No rows deleted for same predicates which give rows in Select statement

Tags: oracle, select, delete-row

```
DELETE
--select * 
FROM T_DIM_TOL
WHERE GTL_ID_DIM_TOL  =:DIMENSION_TOLERANCE_ID
AND GTL_SEC1_COIL_MAX =:THICKNESS_MAX
AND GTL_SEC1_COIL_MIN =:THICKNESS_MIN
AND GTL_SEC2_COIL_MAX =:WIDTH_MAX
AND GTL_SEC2_COIL_MIN =:WIDTH_MIN
and GTL_CD_COMPANY    =:COMPANY_CODE
AND GTL_CD_DEPT       =:DEPT_CODE;
```

When deleting using this query, no row is deleted. But when select is fired with the same predicates, rows are returned ( bind variable value is same )

Answer (score 0):

We get lots of questions of the formulation *when I do this I get this expected result but when I make one simple change I get a wildly unexpected result* . Almost invariably, the solution is that more than 'one simple change' has happened.

In your case I suspect that all the bind variables are not the same.  Try it with hard-coded values and see whether that makes a difference.

There may be other explanations: perhaps there is an ON DELETE trigger which is intercepting and suppressing your statement?  Perhaps T_DIM_TOL is a view with an INSTEAD OF trigger which isn't interpreting the delete statement correctly?

One other thing: how do you know whether no deletions have occurred?  Are you checking SQL%ROWCOUNT?  Or are you querying the table again?  Could it be that the delete has succeeded but you don't see it because you're in a different session and the transaction hasn't been committed?

In short, it will be some idiosyncrasy in your environment which is causing this.

Comment: @LalitKumarB - it's an assumption.  I would be happier if the OP were clearer about what's happening.  Anyway, I don't see that affects my analysis of the underlying cause.

Comment: I removed my comment, I wanted to add few things as `no rows are deleted` is not what Oracle would say, it should be `0 rows deleted.` in SQL*Plus.

Comment: I mentioned you in my answer, if both SQL and PL/SQL shows the rows being deleted, then OP must consider your suggestion. `TRIGGERS` could be really a pain.

Comment: i am using the same session ....and all the bind variables are the same....surprising factor is when i am using sql developer it is showing me zero rows deleted but in case of todd ....it is deleting the record..

Answer (score 0):

With hardcoded values, you should actually see `0 rows deleted.` in SQL*Plus.

Use `SQL%ROWCOUNT` to check if any rows are actually `deleted`.

If you find that rows are actually deleted, but it doesn't reflect the same in the table, then you should look into what @APC has already mentioned.